# Blender UV Problem: Unwraped UV Size different in UV Editor and 3D View

Tags: uv, 3d-view

I am facing this problem :

[image]

My UV doesn't look the same in the 3D Viewport and in the UV editor.

Comment: Maybe [applying the scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html) to all objects helps?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't tell the material to use your UV map, it will use "generated" coordinates by default.

[image]

Comment: While this is true for the checkerboard texture mode it isn’t true for all textures. For image texture, the default coordinates are the first UV map.